# Docker run armv7 images on mac

Tags: macos, docker, x86-64

My mac uses x86_64 hardware and in theory I shouldn't be able to run docker images built for armv7.

HOWEVER

[Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/) says:

> Docker Desktop provides binfmt_misc multi-architecture support, which means you can run containers for different Linux architectures such as arm, mips, ppc64le, and even s390x.
>
> This does not require any special configuration in the container itself as it uses qemu-static from the Docker for Mac VM.

and I'm also reading articles like [this one](https://www.ecliptik.com/Cross-Building-and-Running-Multi-Arch-Docker-Images/) which confirm the above
`docker run -it --rm arm32v7/debian /bin/bash`

should work on a mac although it doesn't work for me:

```
Unable to find image 'arm32v7/debian:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from arm32v7/debian
Digest: sha256:9b61eaedd46400386ecad01e2633e4b62d2ddbab8a95e460f4e0057c612ad085
Status: Image is up to date for arm32v7/debian:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: image with reference arm32v7/debian was found but does not match the specified platform cpu architecture: wanted: amd64, actual: arm.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I wonder whether I'm misunderstanding something.

*Docker desktop community version 2.4.2.0 (48975) edge

Docker version 20.10.0-beta1, build ac365d7

MacOS version 10.15.7 (19H2)*

**Note:** while researching the topic I've tryied to use qemu and ran:
`docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes`
which has potentially interfered with the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I think my problem is related to [this moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36552).

The fix was quite trivial as I only needed to add the `--platform` argument, in my case `linux/arm` or `linux/arm/v7`:
`docker run -it --rm arm32v7/debian /bin/bash`
has become
`docker run --platform=linux/arm  -it --rm arm32v7/debian /bin/bash`

and voila:

```
root@82c3ff8752d3:/# uname -a
Linux 82c3ff8752d3 5.4.39-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri May 8 23:03:06 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```